# Server request uri page and related pages

Tags: php

I'm nearly done with finding a way to show a .html file on certain pages only.

In this case i want test.html to be shown on http://www.example.com/categories/AnyPageThatExcistsInCategories

I figured out the following code works on /categories.
`<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/categories/') { include 'test.html';} ?>`

I only need the golden tip on how to get it also working on pages like /categories/ThisCanBeAnything and categories/ThisCanBeAnything/AndThisAlso etc etc
server config is nginx.

thank you

Comment: I'm not sure of your server environment, but if you are using Apache and enable the rewrite module, you could do it that way.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention it. Its running on nginx.
The code i provided does work perfectly but only on /categories and not /categories/AnythingElse.

Comment: You can use rewrite rules under nginx: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: You could use a regex or partial string comparison. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word-in-php

Comment: Note: `'\categories'` is a different string to `'\categories\'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see if the request uri begins with the string '/categories/':

```
<?php

$request_uri = '/categories/foo';

if (strpos($request_uri, '/categories/') === 0 )
{
    include 'your.html';
}
```

Substitute the value of $request_uri above with `$_SERVER['request_uri']`.  Under the assumption that you have this logic in a front controller.

Further:

```
<?php

$request_uris = [
    '/categories/foo',
    '/categories/',
    '/categories',
    '/bar'
];

function is_category_path($request_uri) {
    $match = false;
    if (strpos($request_uri, '/categories/') === 0 )
    {
        $match =  true;
    }

    return $match;
}

foreach ($request_uris as $request_uri) {
    printf(
        "%s does%s match a category path.\n",
        $request_uri,
        is_category_path($request_uri) ? '' : ' not'
    );
}
```

Output:

```
/categories/foo does match a category path.
/categories/ does match a category path.
/categories does not match a category path.
/bar does not match a category path.
```

In use:

```
if(is_category_path($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    include 'your.html';
    exit;
}
```

You may want to not match the exact string '/categories/', if so you could adjust the conditional:

```
if(
    strpos($request_uri, '/categories/') === 0
    &&                      $request_uri !== '/categories/'
) {}
```

Comment: For some reason this shows the html on all pages all across the website.

ps. "foo" in here `$request_uri = '/categories/foo';` could be anything which i don't know, a digit, a letter, maybe combined.

Comment: One assumes you have `$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, instead of the fixed value given above.  You'll also want to exit after the include.

Answer (score 0):

Progrock's example will work just fine, but here is another example using a regex match instead of strpos, in case you're curious!

```
<?php
if (preg_match("/\/categories\/.*/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    include 'test.html';
}
?>
```

Comment: But in my case, your answer is the only one that works.
Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: You might want to anchor that regex pattern to the beginning of the string: `"/^\/categories\/.*/"`